# What would be the proper way to filter data from query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filtering

I have create simple query that returns me results, depending on your search parameters. So for example if you search for Internal number: 57774

You will get this results:

```
Internal No.    Exchange Time Stamp  Order    Message Type    Exchange Time Stamp
57774           29.5.2014 8:50:00   3506709    DISP.LP    29.5.2014 8:50:00
57774           29.5.2014 8:50:00   3506709    DISP.LP    29.5.2014 8:50:00
57774           29.5.2014 8:50:00   3506709    DISP.LP    29.5.2014 8:50:00
057774          29.5.2014 8:49:08              DISP.NP    29.5.2014 8:49:08
057774          29.5.2014 8:49:08              DISP.NP    29.5.2014 8:49:08
057774          29.5.2014 8:49:08              DISP.NP    29.5.2014 8:49:08
```

Now my new task is, to get all this results into one simple row, that display this data, so for example, for internal number 57774, you would get this simple row displayed:

```
Internal No.   Exxhange Time Stamp    Order   Message Type   Exchange Time Stamp
057774         29.5.2014 8:49:08     3506709    DISP.LP      29.5.2014 8:50:00
```

So this one row should be this:

```
Internal No.: First internal number WHERE is First Date and Time AND If Message type stars with DISP.NP (if is not, return null)
Exch. Time Stamp: 29.5.2014 8:49:08  (First date)
Order: 3506709  (Last order number, if exisits)
Message Type: DISP.LP (Last message type)
Exch. Time Stamp: 29.5.2014 8:50:00 (Last message type)
```

Is there any tutorial how to do this, I was thinking to do this with Linq, I would realy appreciate for any ideas.

Code for my query is this (but it is not relevant to question, It only create my query that It is shown in first table that I posted):

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchParameters parameters)
{
var order = new SortOrder[]
{new SortOrder("sequentialid", Order.DESC), new SortOrder("exchangetimestamp", Order.DESC)};
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SpremenljivkeSolr>>();
var start = (parameters.PageIndex - 1) * parameters.PageSize;
var matchingSpremenljivke = solr.Query(BuildQuery(parameters), new QueryOptions
{
    Rows = parameters.PageSize,
    Start = start,
    OrderBy = order.Concat(GetSelectedSort(parameters)).ToList(),
});

var view = new SpremenljivkeView
{
    Spremenljivke = matchingSpremenljivke,
    Search = parameters,
    TimeZone = timeZone,

};

return View("../LoginUser/Index", view); 
}

public SortOrder[] GetSelectedSort(SearchParameters parameters)
{
    return new[] { SortOrder.Parse(parameters.Sort) }.Where(o => o != null).ToArray();
}

   public ISolrQuery BuildQuery(SearchParameters parameters)
   {
   if (parameters.Destination != null)

   {
    queryInList = new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(
            new[] { new SolrQueryInList("destination", parameters.Destination), new SolrQueryInList("sender", parameters.Destination) },
            "OR");
   }

  var solrQueries = new List<ISolrQuery> { queryInList };

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.Order))
    solrQueries.Add(new SolrQueryByField("order", parameters.Order));


  if (parameters.Exchangetimestamp.HasValue && parameters.Exchangetimestamp2.HasValue)
  {
    solrQueries.Add(new SolrQueryByRange<DateTime>("exchangetimestamp",
        parameters.Exchangetimestamp.Value, parameters.Exchangetimestamp2.Value));
  }
  //and here is same thing solrQueries.Add for Internal

  return new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(solrQueries, "AND");
```

Comment: I have not done anything yet for my problem, but I have pose my code for Query, if helps...

Comment: My problem is how to exactly start, to filter data...

Comment: The actual question seems to have no relation to MVC, filtering or LINQ. Are you asking how to pivot results using a SOLR query, or how to pivot a list of values? In either case, you'd better rewrite your question with the relevant details only. If you *are* asking about filtering ... why don't you do it in the SOLR query?

Comment: "how to pivot a list of values" is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: I apologise for my question if its not clearly asked, I am new at this...

Comment: Have you tried "SELECT DISTINCT"?

Comment: This should be usefull, because I think that distinct would return me from above table only diffrent values. Now I think that my result would be only first and last value (other all same)? But still I need to return from first and sedcond column - first found index; and from orher columns - last found index... I think that my filter that would return me my search parameters would do same, without Distinct... or else, do you have any sugestions.